# Finding largest- and second largest-area contours in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a Python OpenCV script which needs to find the largest and second largest shapes of a specific color on an image. For this, let's see the below sample image. I would like to identify the coordinates of the two pale beige rectangles her:

[image: Sample image]

I managed to obtain the two contours that appear on the mask:

```
img_path = "path\\to\\file.png"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, np.array([21,7,240]), np.array([21,7,255]))
contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
```

The above code returned the following list of lists:

```
[array([[[  8, 245]], [[  7, 246]], [[  6, 246]], [[  6, 247]], [[  5, 248]], [[  0, 248]], [[  0, 300]], [[676, 300]], [[676, 248]], [[675, 247]], [[675, 246]], [[674, 246]], [[673, 245]]], dtype=int32), 
array([[[ 19,  22]], [[ 18,  23]], [[ 18,  24]], [[ 17,  25]], [[ 17, 120]], [[ 18, 121]], [[ 18, 122]], [[ 19, 123]], [[658, 123]], [[659, 122]], [[661, 122]], [[661,  23]], [[659,  23]], [[658,  22]]], dtype=int32)]
```

Now, having the shapes identified, I would like to programatically find the centroids of the first and second largest shapes. Now it's easy as there are only two such shapes but in practice, I might need to deal with dozens on the same image.

I know that `cv2.contourArea(c)` returns the area of a contour and that `cv2.moments(c)` returns the centroid of it (in both cases `c` denoting an element of the `contours` list).

My approach that I tried was the following:

1. organize contours and areas in one dataframe with a `contour` and an `area` columns
2. find the maximum area by `max(df['area'])`
3. find the corresponding dataframe['contour'] whose area is maximal
4. get the centroid of it

This, if it would work, would solve the first half of the problem, i.e. finding the largest-area centroid:

```
contour_area = list()
for c in contours:
    contour_area.append(cv2.contourArea(c))
    M = cv2.moments(c)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'contour': contours,
     'area': contour_area
    })
largest_contour = df.loc[df['area'] == max(df['area']) ]['contour']
centroid = cv2.moments(largest_contour)
```

But when running it, I got `Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'` error message in the last line. I quickly checked the data types and found that the original `contour` elements had a data type of `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` while my `largest_contour` element now had a data type of `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. So I changed the last line to:

```
centroid = cv2.moments(largest_contour.to_numpy())
```

which now ensures that `largest_contour` element has the same data type (`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`) as the `contour` elements had. However, when re-running the code, I got the exact same error message: `Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'array'`.

I would be very grateful for any help or hint on how to move forward!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV colorspace
- Threshold on color
- Get contours
- Create list of (index, area, cx, cy) for all the contours
- Sort the list on area in reverse order
- Print the index, area, cx, cy values for the first two contours
- Draw the two contours in different colors
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('rectangles2.png')

# convert to HSV
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# threshold on color
lower=(21,7,240)
upper=(21,7,255)
thresh = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)

# get contours
result = img.copy() 
cntrs_info = []
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
index=0
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    M = cv2.moments(cntr)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cntrs_info.append((index,area,cx,cy))
    index = index + 1
    #print(index,area,cx,cy)

# sort contours by area
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]
cntrs_info.sort(key=takeSecond, reverse=True)

# get index, area and centroid for first two sorted contours
index_first = cntrs_info[0][0]
area_first = cntrs_info[0][1]
cx_first = cntrs_info[0][2]
cy_first = cntrs_info[0][3]
print("index1:", index_first, "area1:", area_first, "cx1:", cx_first, "cy1:", cy_first)
cv2.drawContours(result,[contours[index_first]],0,(0,0,255),1)

index_second = cntrs_info[1][0]
area_second = cntrs_info[1][1]
cx_second = cntrs_info[1][2]
cy_second = cntrs_info[1][3]
print("index2:", index_second, "area2:", area_second, "cx2:", cx_second, "cy2:", cy_second)
cv2.drawContours(result,[contours[index_second]],0,(0,255,0),1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('rectangles2_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('rectangles2_contours.png',result)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Largest Two Contours:

[image]

Textual Data:

```
index1: 1 area1: 65033.0 cx1: 338 cy1: 71
index2: 0 area2: 37568.0 cx2: 339 cy2: 272
```

Comment: Super helpful response and you even provided some nice extras that I can learn from. Thanks a lot, @fmw42! :)